# Swift: Bolding UIButton

Tags: swift, uibutton, label, uifont

---

Is it possible to bold the font in a UIButton?  With label, it's pretty simple such as:

```
label.font = UIFont(name:"HelveticaNeue-Bold", size: 16.0)
```

But this doesn't work for buttons.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

For a `UIButton` I tried this and works:

**Swift 2**

```
testButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(18)
```

**Swift 3 & 4**

```
testButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 18)
```

(Thank's to  [ConfusionTowers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7106170/confusiontowers))

Comment: Now, `testButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 18)` as of Swift 4 (maybe Swift 3 as well).

Comment: @ciccioska this is not working with iOS 15 button, even I tried to make buttons customs and style default. Can you guide me how to do this in iOS 15 and Xcode 13.2.1?

Comment: @MuhammadDanishQureshi, please check my answer below for the solution to your problem.

Answer (score 5):

**Swift 4+**

```
button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 22.0, weight: .bold)
```

Answer (score 3):

In iOS 15, you have to change the font size and weight using `UIConfigurationTextAttributesTransformer`. The sample code is given below:

```
someButton.configuration?.titleTextAttributesTransformer = UIConfigurationTextAttributesTransformer { incoming in
                var outgoing = incoming
                outgoing.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16, weight: .bold)
                return outgoing
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Click the button you want to bold the text then find **Attributes Inspector**.

[image: Attributes Inspector]

2) After you press the 'Font'. It will pop out something like this image below.

[image: "something pop out"]

3) Press the style and choose "Bold".

4) Click `Done` and it's done.